# Inequality involving integral and second derivative

Tags: calculus, integration

UCLA basic exam spring 2017 problem 8

> Show that there is a constant $C$ so that $$\left| \frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}-\int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm dx \right| \leq C \int_0^1 \lvert f''(x)\rvert \, \mathrm dx$$ for every $C^2$ function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

The domain of $f$ is just $[0, 1]$. For $f''=0$, problem is easy. So the problem is:

Prove that there is a constant $C$ so that $$ \left\{  \frac{ \left| \frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}- \int_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm dx \right|}{ \int_0^1 \lvert f"(x)\rvert \, \mathrm dx} \mid f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \,f \text{ is } C^2, \, f'' \neq 0 \right\} $$ is bounded

Please give a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint for proving from scratch.

**Hint:**
Observe we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{f(1)+f(0)}{2}-\int^1_0 f(x)\ dx =&\ f(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 f'(x)\ dx-\int^1_0\left[f(0)+\int^x_0 f'(\tau)\ d\tau\right] dx\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 f'(x)\ dx-\int^1_0  f'(\tau)(1-\tau)\ d\tau\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}\left[f'(x)x\big|^1_0 -\int^1_0 xf''(x)\ dx \right]-\left[\frac{1}{2}f'(\tau)(1-\tau)^2\big|^1_0-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 f''(\tau)(1-\tau)^2 \right]\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}[f'(1)-f'(0)]+\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 f''(x)((1-x)^2-x)\ dx
\end{align}

In short, use integration by parts.